# Alert always "pending" never "firing" after only (!?) upgrading container versions

Tags: prometheus

> **UPDATES**
>
> 1. Using a different exporter ([`fly-exporter`](https://github.com/DazWilkin/fly-exporter)), alerts fire. If I run the Prometheus|Alertmanager and the `gcp-exporter` on a different host with the ~same config, alerts fire correctly. My hypothesis is that `gcp-exporter` scrapes (!?) are failing (periodically) and the absence of data (I'm unable to confirm this) is what resets the alerts.
> 2. Discovered `ALERTS` synthetic time-series. Prometheus' graph of this, shows gaps. Querying the API `min_over_time(ALERTS{alertname="gcp_cloud_run_services_running"}[12h])` is 1.
> 3. "Active Since" (`activeAt`) is resetting periodically for no reason that's obvious to me. The time-series behind the alerts don't appear to include any 0 values.

I wrote an [exporter](https://github.com/DazWilkin/gcp-exporter) for [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/) services that I use to alert when I'm consuming (more) resources than expected.

It's been working for several months and alerting me (email|[Pushover](https://pushover.net/)).

I think (!?) the only changes I've made recently have been to bump:

1. container image versions

- `docker.io/prom/prometheus:v2.37.0`
- `docker.io/prom/alertmanager:v0.24.0`

1. [google.golang.org/api](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api)

However, I'm no longer (~weeks?) being alerted when I expect to.

This is because the alerts move to "pending" but never "firing".

I don't understand why this is.

The issue is with the Prometheus alert not "firing" and not with AlertManager.

I've definitively been running resources on 2 different monitored services (Cloud Functions; Cloud Run) for longer than 1 day:

```bash
date --rfc-3339=seconds --utc
2022-07-22 22:03:37+00:00

gcloud functions list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(updateTime)"
2020-12-03T20:23:30.940Z # 03-December-2020

gcloud run services list --project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(status.conditions['lastTransitionTime'].slice(0))"
2022-07-21T16:21:24.293561Z # 21-July-2022
2022-07-21T16:20:48.439194Z # 21-July-2022
```

And `/api/v1/alerts`:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "alerts": [
      {
        "labels": {
          "alertname": "gcp_cloud_functions_running",
          "severity": "page"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "summary": "GCP Cloud Functions running"
        },
        "state": "pending",
        "activeAt": "2022-07-22T21:56:02.984175081Z",
        "value": "1e+00"
      },
      {
        "labels": {
          "alertname": "gcp_cloud_run_services_running",
          "severity": "page"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "summary": "GCP Cloud Run services running"
        },
        "state": "pending",
        "activeAt": "2022-07-22T21:56:02.984175081Z",
        "value": "2e+00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> **NOTE** As I'm typing this question, I've noticed that the `activeAt` values are `21:56:02` which is within the 6 hour window. But, why only since then? The resources have existed for longer than that and Prometheus has been been running since (2022-07-21 16:14) when I restarted it thinking it had become wedged.

> **UPDATE** The alerts [`activeAt`](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/414c3e549cf04a63e59af449d3ed13ac4d6d844a/rules/alerting.go#L86) property appears to (be) reset every 30 minutes:
>
> ```
> 2022-07-23T01:26:02.984175081Z
> 2022-07-23T01:26:02.984175081Z
>
> 2022-07-23T00:56:02.984175081Z
> 2022-07-23T00:56:02.984175081Z
> ```
>
> Querying the 2 time-series, I don't find any 0 values that could reset the (`6h`) timer and it's curious that both alerts have the same `activeAt` values (both times)?

And, if I query the time-series:

```bash
QUERY="..." # See below

# Currently 22:03 so this range covers 22 hours' data
START="2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
END="2022-07-22T23:59:59.999Z
STEP="5m"

# Results show by QUERY below
curl \
--silent \
--data-urlencode "query=${QUERY}" \
--data "start=${START}" \
--data "end=${END}" \
--data "step=${STEP}" \
"http://${HOST}:${PORT}/api/v1/query_range" \
| jq -r '.data.result[].values[][1]' \
| sort \
| uniq -c

# Cloud Functions
QUERY="min_over_time(gcp_cloud_functions_functions[15m]>0"
    348 1
     60 2

# Cloud Run
QUERY="min_over_time(gcp_cloud_run_services[15m])>0"
     60 10
    609 2
```

My interpretation of the above is that, for both alerts, the data (admittedly stepped in 5-minute increments) never includes zeros and thus is always `>0` for both queries. Yes, the alerts don't fire.

Questions

1. Why is this?
2. What is my misunderstanding?
3. Is there a better way for me to debug this?

---

`prometheus.yml`:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 1m
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 1m
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - follow_redirects: true
    enable_http2: true
    scheme: http
    timeout: 10s
    api_version: v2
    static_configs:
    - targets:
      - localhost:9093
rule_files:
- /etc/alertmanager/rules.yml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: gcp-exporter
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 15m
  scrape_timeout: 30s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:9402
```

`rules.yml`:

```
groups:
- name: gcp_exporter
  rules:
  - alert: gcp_cloud_functions_running
    expr: min_over_time(gcp_cloud_functions_functions{}[15m]) > 0
    for: 6h
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: GCP Cloud Functions running
  - alert: gcp_cloud_run_services_running
    expr: min_over_time(gcp_cloud_run_services{}[15m]) > 0
    for: 6h
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: GCP Cloud Run services running
```

###### Runtime Information

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "startTime": "2022-07-21T16:14:23.941571056Z",
    "CWD": "/prometheus",
    "reloadConfigSuccess": true,
    "lastConfigTime": "2022-07-21T16:14:23Z",
    "corruptionCount": 0,
    "goroutineCount": 43,
    "GOMAXPROCS": 4,
    "GOGC": "",
    "GODEBUG": "",
    "storageRetention": "15d"
  }
}
```

###### Build Information

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "version": "2.37.0",
    "revision": "b41e0750abf5cc18d8233161560731de05199330",
    "branch": "HEAD",
    "buildUser": "root@0ebb6827e27f",
    "buildDate": "20220714-15:19:21",
    "goVersion": "go1.18.4"
  }
}
```

###### Alertmanagers

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "activeAlertmanagers": [
      {
        "url": "http://localhost:9093/api/v2/alerts"
      }
    ],
    "droppedAlertmanagers": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confident that the underlying issue was my mistaken use of overly long `scrape_interval` values.

I'd had:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: gcp-exporter
  scrape_interval: 15m
```

I realized that this results in periods of 15-minute of measurements of alerts with 1-minute gaps:

[image]

Yesterday, I read Brian Brazil's [Keep It Simple `scrape_interval`](https://www.robustperception.io/keep-it-simple-scrape_interval-id/) and I reverted the `scrape_interval` to the `global` value of `scrape_interval: 1m`.

Now, the `ALERT` metrics appear continuous and, most importantly, alerts are firing as expected:

[image]